# LUKS and /etc/crypttab on centos 7 - hang at startup

Tags: centos7, luks

I have a problem with following crypttab
echo "secret /dev/sdb8       none" > /etc/crypttab

When I do it by hand, following way everything is ok, disk is mounted:

```
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdb8
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb8 secret
ll /dev/mapper/
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/secret
mount /dev/mapper/secret /secret/

umount /secret/
cryptsetup luksClose /dev/mapper/secret
```

With /etc/crypttab filled as below

```
echo "secret /dev/sdb8       none" > /etc/crypttab
```

centos 7 hungs at startup.
How can I debug it ? 
What and where should I grep ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do not need the luksClose line unless you want to stop using luks

Comment: I trust You, cause I cannot verify now if this hint works (that system is already down and I don't play with cryptsetup any more)